# Module Pattern in Coffeescript with hidden Variables

Tags: javascript, module, design-patterns, coffeescript

Digging into Coffeescript I am trying to port my Javascript files to Coffeescript.

Concerning this, I have a question related to the module pattern of Doulgas Crockford (closure binding in order to keep variables "private")

Therefore my question is: What would the aquivalent Coffeescript for the following JS look like:

```
var test = function () { var hidden = 'open'; return { open: hidden }; }();
```

Respectively, is there a different / better aproach to this pattern in Coffeescript?

Answer (score 17):

I think the best approach is to literally translate your example into CoffeeScript, with the help of the `do` keyword (which exists mainly to capture values in loops—see my [PragPub article](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-05/a-coffeescript-intervention)):

```
test = do ->
  hidden = 'open'
  open: hidden
```

This compiles to

```
var test;
test = (function() {
  var hidden;
  hidden = 'open';
  return {
    open: hidden
  };
})();
```

which is identical to your code other than formatting. (The CoffeeScript compiler automatically puts all `var` declarations at the top of their scope, which makes it easy to determine how a variable is scoped by looking at the JavaScript output.)

Comment: "which exists mainly to capture values in loops" < Disagreed. That particular behavior of `do` is arguably one of the most incosistent/confusing features.

Comment: Matyr, can you explain that? The do keyword looks like it captures values in a local scope to me.

Comment: @matyr It wasn't the intended purpose of `do` when you initially proposed it, but it's certainly the reason why Jeremy (reluctantly) added it to CoffeeScript. See [issue 959](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/959). It's also the only context in which `do` appears in the [official docs](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#loops).

Comment: As I've argued in [#788](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/788), the feature breaks consistency (why should `do(i)->` and `do f=(i)->` behave differently?). The fact that it's less documented is only another flaw (it was a last minute change for Christmas after all).

Comment: Why should they indeed. I noted that earlier today at [#960](github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/960). I certainly hope Jeremy will choose to fix the inconsistencies rather than abandoning the feature.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer(s)!

I managed to solve my problem. I'm not really sure whether opening a new question would be better but I came across another point which requires me to ask another question. Comprehensions are pretty useful, but what about a case when I know that there is only one element I am looking for? For instance, found = (a for a of b when a.something is 'something')
In case I know that there is only one element to be found how can I grab the respective object directly without having to access it by writing found[0]

Comment: @R I'd post a new question for that. I check for new questions tagged [coffeescript] pretty frequently.

Answer (score 6):

I added a section to the coffeescript wiki on how I handle namespacing. It's pretty elegent ( I think )

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Easy-modules-with-coffeescript

Coffeescript does not have a native module system above that of enclosing all source code files in an anonymous function. However with a bit of simple trickery you can have modules that are the envy of Ruby.
I define my modules like below

```
@module "foo", ->
    @module "bar", ->
        class @Amazing
            toString: "ain't it"
```

The implementation of the module helper is

```
window.module = (name, fn)->
  if not @[name]?
    this[name] = {}
  if not @[name].module?
    @[name].module = window.module
  fn.apply(this[name], [])
```

which you can put in another source file if you like. You can then access your classes by namespaced modules

```
x = new foo.bar.Amazing
```

wrt to your specific question I think the below jasmine spec answer it using my
module system

```
@module "test", ->
  hidden = 10
  @open  = hidden

describe "test", ->
  it "has no hidden", ->
    expect(test.hidden?).toEqual false

  it "has  open", ->
    expect(test.open?).toEqual true
```

Comment: That Wiki page (https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Easy-modules-with-coffeescript) doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 5):

CoffeeScript (or rather, the `coffee` script) automatically wraps your code within an anonymous function unless you tell it not to.

If you need to publish objects from within that anonymous closure, you can explicitly assign them to the root object; see the start of Underscore.coffee for some pointers.

http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/documentation/docs/underscore.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can write your module in a single class, then compiling the coffeescript with the `-b` option will naturally create the module pattern you're looking for.

This:

```
class test
    hidden = 'open'
    open: hidden
```

compiles to this:

```js
var test;
test = (function() {
    var hidden;
    hidden = 'open';

    test.prototype.open = hidden;

    return test;
})();
```

which is very nearly what you were looking for.